# How to implement a linq expression for maximum in different nodes?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have the following xml:
https://pastebin.pl/view/63af9294

I should find the name of the battle where the highest army fought.
(Yes, it's a school work, but i'm not getting any closer)

So far my code looks like:

```
        var q10 = (from a in
                       (from x in xdoc.Descendants("size") select x)
                    join b in
                         (from y in xdoc.Descendants("battle") select y)
                    on a equals b.Element("attacker").Element("size")
                    select new
                    {
                        size = a.Value,
                        battle = b.Element("name")
                    });
```

I am trying to get the highest number first, than join every battle by the size and than use a
`.Max(x => x.size)` , but as you see i have no clue how to do it for 2 different nodes, or whatever called.
I mean i can join the attacker or the defender based on the size of an army but cannot join both of them in the same time, unless i use 2 joins, but i guess it could be done much easier and nicer. I don't want to write the code, just need some tips.

Comment: If you sort and the group the object  stay in order.   So add to end of your query after the closing parenthesis : .OrderByDescending(x => x.size).GroupBy(x => x.battle).Select(x => x.First()).ToList();

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understand what you need, I would go this way:

```
var battle = xDoc.Descendants("battle")
       .OrderByDescending(b => GetMaxBattleArmySize(b))
       .First();
```

where `GetMaxArmySize` is

```
private static int GetMaxBattleArmySize(XElement battle)
{
    XElement attacker = battle.Element("attacker");
    XElement defender = battle.Element("defender");

    var attackerSizeEl = attacker.Element("size");
    var defenderSizeEl = defender.Element("size");

    var attackerSize = attackerSizeEl == null
            ? 0
            : int.Parse(attackerSizeEl.Value);

    var defenderSize = defenderSizeEl == null
            ? 0
            : int.Parse(defenderSizeEl.Value);

    return Math.Max(attackerSize, defenderSize);
 }
```